# UrbanAirship getting crash of NullPointerException when Activity (or RAM) is cleaned from device

Tags: android, push-notification, urbanairship.com

I'm trying to implement my app with UrbanAirship Push Notifications.

When I start the application and it's in background (but active) I receive push notifications correctly, but when I send a push notification when my app is cleaned (because my device needs space or because I cleaned de RAM) I get a crash.

This is the LogCat:

> > 04-16 16:09:34.082: E/AndroidRuntime(19680): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 04-16 16:09:34.082: E/AndroidRuntime(19680):
> >     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver
> >     com.urbanairship.push.GCMPushReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException
> >     04-16 16:09:34.082: E/AndroidRuntime(19680):  at
> >     android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2258)
> >     04-16 16:09:34.082: E/AndroidRuntime(19680):  at
> >     android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:134) 04-16
> >     16:09:34.082: E/AndroidRuntime(19680):    at
> >     android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293)
> >     04-16 16:09:34.082: E/AndroidRuntime(19680):  at
> >     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 04-16
> >     16:09:34.082: E/AndroidRuntime(19680):    at
> >     android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 04-16 16:09:34.082:
> >     E/AndroidRuntime(19680):  at
> >     android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4856) 04-16
> >     16:09:34.082: E/AndroidRuntime(19680):    at
> >     java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 04-16
> >     16:09:34.082: E/AndroidRuntime(19680):    at
> >     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 04-16 16:09:34.082:
> >     E/AndroidRuntime(19680):  at
> >     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
> >     04-16 16:09:34.082: E/AndroidRuntime(19680):  at
> >     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774) 04-16
> >     16:09:34.082: E/AndroidRuntime(19680):    at
> >     dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 04-16 16:09:34.082:
> >     E/AndroidRuntime(19680): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
> >     04-16 16:09:34.082: E/AndroidRuntime(19680):  at
> >     com.urbanairship.push.PushService.acquireWakeLock(PushService.java:341)
> >     04-16 16:09:34.082: E/AndroidRuntime(19680):  at
> >     com.urbanairship.push.PushService.runGcmIntentInService(PushService.java:160)
> >     04-16 16:09:34.082: E/AndroidRuntime(19680):  at
> >     com.urbanairship.push.GCMPushReceiver.onReceive(GCMPushReceiver.java:80)
> >     04-16 16:09:34.082: E/AndroidRuntime(19680):  at
> >     android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2251)
> >     04-16 16:09:34.082: E/AndroidRuntime(19680):  ... 10 more

and sometimes I get this together with this one:

> > 04-16 15:19:00.420: E/UA AP(10730): Unable to takeOff automatically 04-16 15:19:00.420: D/AndroidRuntime(10730): Shutting down VM 04-16
> >     15:19:00.430: W/dalvikvm(10730): threadid=1: thread exiting with
> >     uncaught exception (group=0x412462a0) 04-16 15:19:00.430:
> >     E/AndroidRuntime(10730): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 04-16 15:19:00.430:
> >     E/AndroidRuntime(10730): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create
> >     service com.urbanairship.analytics.EventService:
> >     java.lang.NullPointerException 04-16 15:19:00.430:
> >     E/AndroidRuntime(10730):  at
> >     android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2395)
> >     04-16 15:19:00.430: E/AndroidRuntime(10730):  at
> >     android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:134) 04-16
> >     15:19:00.430: E/AndroidRuntime(10730):    at
> >     android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1299)
> >     04-16 15:19:00.430: E/AndroidRuntime(10730):  at
> >     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 04-16
> >     15:19:00.430: E/AndroidRuntime(10730):    at
> >     android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 04-16 15:19:00.430:
> >     E/AndroidRuntime(10730):  at
> >     android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4856) 04-16
> >     15:19:00.430: E/AndroidRuntime(10730):    at
> >     java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 04-16
> >     15:19:00.430: E/AndroidRuntime(10730):    at
> >     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 04-16 15:19:00.430:
> >     E/AndroidRuntime(10730):  at
> >     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
> >     04-16 15:19:00.430: E/AndroidRuntime(10730):  at
> >     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774) 04-16
> >     15:19:00.430: E/AndroidRuntime(10730):    at
> >     dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 04-16 15:19:00.430:
> >     E/AndroidRuntime(10730): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
> >     04-16 15:19:00.430: E/AndroidRuntime(10730):  at
> >     com.urbanairship.analytics.EventService.onCreate(EventService.java:96)
> >     04-16 15:19:00.430: E/AndroidRuntime(10730):  at
> >     android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2385)
> >     04-16 15:19:00.430: E/AndroidRuntime(10730):  ... 10 more

***Could be a library error???***

This is my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AirshipConfigOptions options = AirshipConfigOptions.loadDefaultOptions(this.getApplication());
    UAirship.takeOff(this.getApplication(), options);
    PushManager.enablePush();
    PushManager.shared().setIntentReceiver(IntentReceiver.class);
    getWindow();
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

[...]

my AndroidManifext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="MY_PACKAGE_NAME_ALREADY_WRITTEN"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<!-- Required for the Urban Airship library -->
<permission android:name="MY_PACKAGE_NAME_ALREADY_WRITTEN.permission.UA_DATA" 
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="MY_PACKAGE_NAME_ALREADY_WRITTEN.permission.UA_DATA" />  

<!-- Required for Push -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

<!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

<!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<!-- This app has permission to register with GCM and receive message -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<permission android:name="MY_PACKAGE_NAME_ALREADY_WRITTEN.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" 
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="MY_PACKAGE_NAME_ALREADY_WRITTEN.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />



<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="AIzaSyBYtJ0bj7ckKWN8drcwYYvnAy_Sbb8y4Xk"/>

<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" 
    android:value="@string/APP_ID"/>


    <!-- Required for the library -->
<provider android:name="com.urbanairship.UrbanAirshipProvider"
          android:authorities="MY_PACKAGE_NAME_ALREADY_WRITTEN.urbanairship.provider"
          android:permission="MY_PACKAGE_NAME_ALREADY_WRITTEN.permission.UA_DATA"
          android:exported="true"
          android:multiprocess="true" />

<!-- Required for Push -->
<service android:name="com.urbanairship.push.PushService"/>
<receiver android:name="com.urbanairship.CoreReceiver" />
<receiver android:name="com.urbanairship.push.GCMPushReceiver" 
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

        <category android:name="MY_PACKAGE_NAME_ALREADY_WRITTEN" />
    </intent-filter>

    <!--  Required for detecting when the application is upgraded so it can request a new GCM ID -->
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
        <data android:scheme="package"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<receiver android:name="MY_PACKAGE_NAME_ALREADY_WRITTEN.IntentReceiver" />

<!-- Required for analytics -->
<service android:name="com.urbanairship.analytics.EventService"/>

<!-- Required for Rich Push -->
<service android:name="com.urbanairship.richpush.RichPushUpdateService"/>

<!-- Required for Actions -->
<activity android:name="com.urbanairship.actions.ActionActivity"/>
<service android:name="com.urbanairship.actions.ActionService"/>

<!-- Required for Landing Page Action -->
<activity
    android:name="com.urbanairship.actions.LandingPageActivity"
    android:parentActivityName="MY_PACKAGE_NAME_ALREADY_WRITTEN.MainActivity"
    android:exported="false">

    <!-- MODIFICATION REQUIRED set or remove the parent activity -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="MY_PACKAGE_NAME_ALREADY_WRITTEN.splash" />

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.urbanairship.actions.SHOW_LANDING_PAGE_INTENT_ACTION"/>
        <data android:scheme="http" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

    <activity
        android:name="MY_PACKAGE_NAME_ALREADY_WRITTEN.splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
android:label="@string/title_facebook_login" >
    </activity>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
             android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

        <activity android:name=".HomeActivity"
             android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

</application>
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Oh, I've seen looking on forums (UA and StackOverflow) and didn't find anything.

Comment: IT seems that takeOff should be called into Application onCreate and not Activity onCreate.